# Logstash: How to read single-line JSON

Tags: json, file-io, logstash

I am trying to figure out how to read in a JSON file with Logstash that contains all of the events on one single line

Sample input:

```
{"metadata": {"metadata fields": "metadata data"},"results": [{"events":[{"event fields": "event data"}, {"event fields": "event data"}}],"field": {"more fields": "data"}}
```

Expanded JSON:

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "metadata fields": "metadata data"
    },
    "results": [{
            "events": [{
                    "event fields": "event data"
                }, {
                    "event fields": "event data"
                }
            }], "field": {
            "more fields": "data"
        }
    }
```

I have tried just using the JSON codec however, when I run Logstash it hangs after print successfully started. Another thing I have tried that gets it to work is adding a newline at the end of the JSON but this won't work in production because I have no control over the source of the logs.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to correctly parse these logs through Logstash? Below is my configuration file. Thanks in advance!

Config

```
input {
    file {
        path => "C:/Folder/*.json"
        sincedb_path => "C:\nul"
        start_position => "beginning"
        codec => "json"
        type => "data"
    }
}
output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Comment: That is not valid JSON. Probably the reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have any ideas how I can parse it then?

Comment: Some elaborate `grok` filter will do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input is missing a square bracket, it should have one:

```
{"metadata": {"metadata fields": "metadata data"},"results": [{"events":[{"event fields": "event data"}, {"event fields": "event data"} HERE ] }],"field": {"more fields": "data"}}
```

If the missing square bracket is in front of the same event in all your input files, you could try `gsub`.

For example:

```
filter {
 mutate {
   gsub => [ "message", "\"}}\],\"field\"\:", "\"}\]}\],\"field\"\:" ]
 }
}
```

This matches **"}}],"field":** pattern and replaces it with a similar one, but with added **[** in the right place. After this mutation you can go ahead using json filter to the message.